# Django autocomplete: AttributeError: module 'dal_select2.models' has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

My `models.py`:

```
from dal import autocomplete
from dal_select2_queryset_sequence.views import *
from queryset_sequence import QuerySetSequence
from dal.widgets import *
from dal.views import *
from dal_queryset_sequence.views import *
from dal_select2 import *
from dal_queryset_sequence import *


class Test(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'dal_queryset_sequence',
    'django.contrib.admin'
...]
```

But the system throws out

> AttributeError: module 'dal_select2.models' has no attribute 'Model'.

Tried to add "from dal_select2.models import Model or *", but not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why you shouldn't use the `from x import *`. One of those modules you import - `dal_select_2` - defines a name `models`, which overrides the one you actually wanted which is from `django.db`.

Only import the names you actually use, then this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dal` and `dal_select2` to the INSTALLED_APPS